# running python script from another python script on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows

There is one liner python script:

```
# inner.py
print "hello"
```

When I create another script:

```
import os
os.system('python inner.py > out.txt')
```

and execute it from the command line, everything works as expected, "hello" is written in out.txt

When I replace os.system argument with:

```
os.system('inner.py > out.txt')
```

and execute the script, I get following error:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

If I don't redirect output, I get "hello" on console in both cases.

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

Why do I get an error ?

Comment: if you open a command window can you run python scripts without specifying python? ie `C:> runme.py` works? (more specifically `runme.py > somefile.txt` works?

Comment: 99.99% of the time, you shouldn't use `system` to execute other python scripts. You should use `import`.

Comment: As Joran Beasley was asking, are you sure that the command you're trying to run with os.system() actually works.  If you try that exact command from the shell does it do what you want?  As Kevin noted though, there may be other ways to accomplish this task that are more pythonic.

Comment: (Sorry for delay) yes, I can run python scrips from command line. Yes, if I run command from the shell, it works as expected. I know that I can use subprocess commands, I'm just curious why os.system does not work as it should and I think that it's win7 fault but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `execfile` function instead:

```
execfile('inner.py') # in the outer script
```

Comment: Thx. In fact, my real life problem looks like os.system("cmda.py | cmdb.exe") and cmdb doesn't get anything from stdin. execfile does not help in this case, and os.system should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the output of the file use `subprocess.check_call` and redirect the stdout to the file object:

```
from subprocess import check_call

with open("out.txt",'w') as f:
    check_call(["python", "/path/to/inner.py"], stdout=f)
```

It won't work for your print example unless you redirect `sys.stdout` to the file object  but if you actually have functions that return something in another module you can import them and then write the output to a file without using subprocess.

Comment: Thx. I can make this work but os.system is so much simpler and more natural to me, so I would like to know why it doesn't work.